# Android Seek bar text width out of range

Tags: android

[image]Here am using `seek bar` with `text view`. when I change `seek bar` the `text view` also moving. when I came last position of `seek bar` the `text view` out of the range.

please,any one help where I am doing wrong.

Here am sharing my `code`. when I change `seek bar` I want move the `text view` along with seek bar position.

```
    // Seek bar code         
    seekbar_pay_restaurant_.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    //change position of seekebar tool tip according to seekbar progress               
                    int x = seekBar.getThumb().getBounds().left;
                    Log.v("y value ",""+x);
                    int width = seekBar.getThumb().getMinimumWidth();
                    int textWidth=tv_tool_type_food_.getMeasuredWidth();
                    Log.v("textview Width","width"+textWidth);
                    Log.v("width",""+ width);
                    tv_tool_type_food_.setX(x);
                    if (seekbar_pay_restaurant_.getProgress() == 0) {
                        tv_tool_type_food_.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.hint_fast_food__));
                        // tv_tool_type_food_.setX(y);
                        return ;
                    } else if (progress == 1) {
                        tv_tool_type_food_.setX(x);
                        tv_tool_type_food_.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.hint_fast_casual__));
                        return ;
                    } else if (progress == 2) {
                      // tv_tool_type_food_.setX(x );
                        tv_tool_type_food_.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.hint_casual__));
                        return;
                    } else if (progress == 3) {
                          tv_tool_type_food_.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.hint_fine_dyning__));
                        return;
                    }
                    tv_tool_type_food_.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.hint_fast_food__));
                }
                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }
            });
// seek bar xml file 
<SeekBar
                                android:id="@+id/seekbar_pay_restaurant"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:max="3"
                                android:progress="0"
                                android:thumbOffset="@dimen/two_dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/twenty_dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/five_dp"
                                />
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv_tool_type_food"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                style="@style/label_white_h13"
                                android:background="@drawable/tooltip_bg"
                                android:typeface="normal"
                                android:text="@string/hint_fast_food__"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/seven_dp"
                                android:paddingRight="@dimen/seven_dp"
                                android:paddingTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/ten_dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/one_sp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/one_dp"/>
```

Comment: try this `int x = seekBar.getThumb().getBounds().left -  tv_tool_type_food.getWidth;`

Comment: Thanks Muhammad for your reply

Answer (score 0):

```
// Seek bar code          
    seekbar_pay_restaurant_.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() { 
                @Override 
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    //change position of seekebar tool tip according to seekbar progress                
                    int x = seekBar.getThumb().getBounds().left;
                    Log.v("y value ",""+x);
                    int width = seekBar.getThumb().getMinimumWidth();
                    int textWidth=tv_tool_type_food_.getMeasuredWidth();
                    Log.v("textview Width","width"+textWidth);
                    Log.v("width",""+ width);
                    if(x < max_x ) { // This will prevent the movement of text view out side
                       tv_tool_type_food_.setX(x);
                    }
                    if (seekbar_pay_restaurant_.getProgress() == 0) { 
                        tv_tool_type_food_.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.hint_fast_food__));
                        // tv_tool_type_food_.setX(y); 
                        return ; 
                    } else if (progress == 1) {
                        tv_tool_type_food_.setX(x);
                        tv_tool_type_food_.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.hint_fast_casual__));
                        return ; 
                    } else if (progress == 2) {
                      // tv_tool_type_food_.setX(x ); 
                        tv_tool_type_food_.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.hint_casual__));
                        return; 
                    } else if (progress == 3) {
                          tv_tool_type_food_.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.hint_fine_dyning__));
                        return; 
                    } 
                    tv_tool_type_food_.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.hint_fast_food__));
                } 
                @Override 
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                } 

                @Override 
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                } 
            });
```

Best way to calculate that value is

```
int seek_bar_width = seekbar.getMeasuredWidth();
int text_view_with = textview.getMeasuredWidth();
int max_x = seekbar.getX()+seek_bar_width-text_view_with;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Charan ,As per your code when seek bar last position the text view is in seek bar second position.

Comment: Yes, But it doesn't get cut in right. If you  have space in screen on right or left try adding padding to the left and right of seekbar view.
If there is no space on screen itself then only way is to stop text view if it exceeds max_x value or decrease the size of text view once it reaches the max_x value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the text view with the seekbar position, then you will need to add this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();

if (textview.getX() > width-textview.getLayoutParams().width) {
   textview.setX(width-textview.getLayoutParams().width);
}
```

This "if" will prevent doing that problem.